# Internet explorer 8 html file download opening in same window

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, download

I have a servelt which downloads the selected file.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\00002997\\Desktop\\abc.html");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte [] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            fis.read(bytes);
            fis.close();

            //Downlaod code starts

            ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+file.getName());

            sos.write(bytes);
            sos.flush();
            sos.close();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

//JSP file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="FileDownloadServlet" method="get">

<input type="submit" value="Download" >

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I say download other than html file it works fine

[image]

When I say open it is opening in MS word which is fine.

But when I say download (ext : abc.html) html pages the current download page is replaced by abc.html page.

[image]

And when I say open from donwload pop - up . this is what happening.
[image]

It is replacing the download page with downloaded html file .

And My question is is there any way to force the download rather than asking for opening from download pop-up.

or any other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Add this header : 
    Content-Type: application/force-download

This will fix this problem on IE :)